# IOS Simulator rotates despite Info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My Situation:
I have selected in the Infoplist file for IOS that my app should only run in landscape mode. In spite of this, in the simulator, when I turn the Ipad, I can still go into portrait mode. Unfortunately, I can't try it out on physical devices because I don't have one yet. Can someone help me there?

[image: InfoPlist]

[image]

Comment: Is this on iPhone or iPad? You say tablet so it sounds like iPad. If so, that's the reason. You cannot just say you want a landscape iPad app.

Comment: @matt yes i mean Ipad. I want the app to start and stay in landscape mode like on Android with including  ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape) in MainActivity.cs

Comment: Then you must add the UIRequiresFullScreen setting. Otherwise your landscape setting is ignored. But I must warn you that Apple has announced they will stop obeying this directive.

Comment: @matt i read the associated Question but this dosnt solve the Problem. I need it to stay in Landscape. Setting UIRequiresFullScreen  to yes dosnt change anything.....